# How to use Intel Quick Sync/iGPU in OVH dedicated server

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu, ovh, vga

I have a dedicated server with the following HW:

```
CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) E-2386G CPU @ 3.50GHz
Motherboard: Manufacturer: ASRockRack, Product Name: E3C252D4U-2T/OVH
```

According to the Intel website, E-2386G has Intel Quick Sync, and I want to use it.
I tried to check which VGA I have in the system (expected to see Intel + the local), and this is the output:

```
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 41)
```

I.e., the Intel iGPU doesn't recognize at all in the system, I tried to check in `/dev/dri` what are the existing devices there, and this is the output:

```
ls -alh /dev/dri
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root      80 Sep 19 10:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root    4.2K Sep 20 13:05 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root      60 Sep 19 10:28 by-path
crw-rw----  1 root video 226, 0 Sep 19 10:28 card0
```

When I tried to run `vainfo` tool, I get the following results:

Vanilla run:

```
vainfo
error: can't connect to X server!
libva info: VA-API version 1.7.0
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

Run after setting `export LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=i965`:

```
vainfo
error: can't connect to X server!
libva info: VA-API version 1.7.0
libva info: User environment variable requested driver 'i965'
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_6
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

Run with sudo:

```
sudo vainfo
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
error: can't connect to X server!
libva info: VA-API version 1.7.0
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

How can I use Intel Quick Sync?

--- edit ---

Running the suggested commands:

```
vainfo --display DRM
libva info: VA-API version 1.7.0
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit

vainfo --display wayland
error: failed to initialize display 'wayland'

vainfo --display help
Available displays:
  wayland
  x11
  DRM


sudo journalctl -b | grep i965  (no results)
```

Comment: have you been able to solve the problem? please at least some quick short anwser (one sentence, yes no what solved) thanks a lot! :)

Comment: No - `ovh` said there is no way to do so, not sure how or why they block this option

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ vainfo --display drm
```

Or:

```
$ vainfo --display wayland
```

And if neither works: `vainfo --display help` to see which display options you have.

To see if your kernel knows about your iGPU:

```
$ sudo journalctl -b | grep i965
```

If nothing shows up, maybe it didn't load the kernel module for it?

Comment: I run the commands, `grep i965` not fins anything, `vainfo --display drm` has error, I edited the question with the output of those commands